# CouchDB kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, couchdb, kubernetes-operator

I need to deploy couchdb in our production environment, and I've been trying to use the couchdb operator (https://operatorhub.io/operator/couchdb-operator) in order to make the deployed cluster more resilient.
I've tried using the official helm chart but it’s not stable enough for us.

Our couchdb deployment needs to use an image in our private repository, and we need to configure an internal sidecar application that will be deployed as a container in the same pod in each node in the cluster.

I went over the documentation here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-apache-couchdb-operator
I couldn’t find any reference here to using my own images or configuring sidecar applications, I also tried accessing the couchdb-operator pod and tried looking for something I can use, couldn't find anything helpful.

I'm not too experienced in kubernetes operators as a whole, so this might seem counter-intuitive to using operators, but my question is: can I somehow edit the code for the operator so I can configure external configuration like defining my own repositories/image, sidecars, or even services?

Thanks in advance,
Dean.

Comment: What do you mean by "it’s not stable enough for us"? You can change the configuration with Kubernetes YAML, but the solution will be based on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, the operator manages the entire lifecycle of the application, so if for instance 1 pod would fail and be rescheduled, if we're using the operator, the new node would join the couchdb cluster without any problems.

From what I've noticed with helm, if one pod needs to be rescheduled, it doesn't join the cluster properly and we need to re-deploy, so it's not stable enough (this means that if 1 pod needs to be rescheduled then the entire deployment needs to be rescheduled)